# Connect multiple local git repos to one remote repository

Tags: git

I'm pretty sure this won't work at all, but I thought I'd throw something out to the big brains on SO just in case :)

I have two local git repositories. One of them is pretty new, but the other one has a few branches and some useful history I would like to preserve.

My team wanted cloud hosting for our git repository, but they only set up one repository remotely. Getting multiple repositories is unfortunately not an option.

What I would like is to keep my local repos as my working copies, preserving the existing history and building new history on top of that. Then I'd like the ability to set it up so I can push to a directory in the remote repository.

So it will look like:

**Local**

```
~/src/repo1
|---file1.c
|---file2.c
~/src/repo2
|---file1.js
|---file2.html
```

**Remote**

```
bigrepo.git
|---repo1/
|-------file1.c
|-------file2.c
|---repo2/
|-------file1.js
|-------file2.html
```

Thanks in advance!